# List inside ScrollView is not displayed on WatchOs

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list inside a scrollview and it is not displaying below the image and the buttons. I've also tried to put the list and other items inside of a VStack and that allows me to see one item of the list at the time opposed  to scrolling past the Image and buttons to show the whole list.

```
    ScrollView{
        Image(uiImage: self.image)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
            .scaledToFit()

        Text("\(name)")
            .lineLimit(2)
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                print("button1")
            }){
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("button 2")
            }){
                Image(systemName: "trash")

            }
        }
        List{
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                VStack{
                    Text(item.name)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .lineLimit(1)

                    Text(item.subname)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Tittle"))
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
```

Ive also tried to add `.frame( minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)`
 to the list to force it to have its whole height and that did not work either. Any suggestions or might this be a swiftUI bug ?

**EDIT**

I just realized Im getting this error when scrolling:

```
APPNAME Watch Extension[336:60406] [detents] could not play detent NO, 2, Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-536870187 "(null)", (
        {
        Gain = "0.01799999922513962";
        OutputType = 0;
        SlotIndex = 4;
    },
        {
        Gain = "0.6000000238418579";
        OutputType = 1;
        SlotIndex = 5;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Indicate some height for your List like

```
 List{
      ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
          VStack{
              Text(item.name)
                   .font(.headline)
                   .lineLimit(1)

              Text(item.subname)
                   .font(.subheadline)
                   .lineLimit(1)
          }
      }
 }.frame(minHeight: 200, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the `List` inside of a `GeometryReader` and setting the `frame` there?

Comment: I've tried putting  just the` List` inside `GeometryReader` and it didn't work, just half a row appears and the Image, Text, and HStack do not scroll. Ive also tried to put the Image, Text, and HStack alongside the List inside the geometry reader and it also doesn't work and also appears to create more problems (i.e. the image text and buttons are all in weird places).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with UIKit. The error message is related to haptic feedback, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1628128-play).
It says that a haptic feedback could not be played, probably type 2, i.e. `directionDown`, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkhaptictype).
Since my code does not call `play(_:)`, it must be called by watchOS itself.
The reason for the error might be very fast scrolling, which could result in too frequent calls to `play(_:)` that cannot be handled properly. The docs say:

> Do not call this method multiple times in quick succession. If the
> haptic engine is already engaged when you call this method, the system
> stops the current feedback and imposes a minimum delay of 100
> milliseconds before engaging the engine to generate the new feedback.

If this is really an effect of watchOS, I guess you cannot do anything to avoid the error.